# Proper order to tile niche

Tags: tile

I have a shower niche that will have a quartz sill and shelf. It’ll look something like this.

[image]

Wall around it is tiled and I’ll also be using Schluter tile edging for the left, right and top sides of the niche. What’s the proper order to install everything in the niche?

I was thinking:

1. Niche back wall
2. Sill
3. Left and right sides up to shelf
4. Shelf sitting on sides
5. Ceiling of niche
6. Rest of left and right sides up to ceiling of niche

Comment: From back to front :-)  Personally I would hate to be bumping into sticky out bits when my eyes are closed in the shower.

Comment: Not a specific answer to your question, but make sure those shelves have a very slight angle to them to keep water from pooling in the back of the niches.  The contractor that built our shower didn't do that, and so we have water puddling up in the back.

Answer (score 1):

What you suggest may work just fine, I would go about it a little differently. When all the waterproofing is done, set the sill first, then set the back wall of the niche. After that, set the sides and that, when cut properly and if the tile is long enough, the sides may support the top piece using a few tile spacers to make a grout joint, and set the top of the niche in the thinset.

After all that has set up, cut the tile edging, taping it in place until enough wall tile is in to keep it stable, and I would still tape it again after the tile is dry, (from wiping the surface while tiling, not after the thinset is dry) taping it to the tile, to be certain it doesn't try to sneak back out. Do this ASAP so the thinset doesn't get its initial set so it doesn't dislodge anything that you have set already.

Answer (score 0):

There are just a few simple considerations when doing something like this (or base trim in a small room, for another example):

1. Structure. What needs to hold up what?
2. Access. If you do one thing first, does it preclude you from finishing the job somehow?
3. Appearance. Generally speaking you want to look *across* butt joints rather than into them, from the most common or most important viewing angle. That means the back wall would generally be done first, with the sides butting into it.